# signal/sense connectors rated for 400-600V, a few milliamps

Tags: connector, high-voltage

Anyone familiar with connectors that have large enough spacing to support the creepage/clearance requirements for 400-600V, but that don't need to carry much current (only a few milliamps at most)?

We're presently using Molex Sabre connectors which are rated at 600V 18A but it's silly to need such a large contact. The spacing is what I need, not the contact size.

**edit:** I am looking for multipin systems with between 4 and 8 contacts.

Any suggestions? (besides buying smaller connectors and leaving out every other pin -- that's not very manufacturable unless the manufacturer offers this as a standard option)

I am offering an "honor system bounty" of 100 points: if I get an answer that is an improvement over the Sabre connector, I'll accept the best one and add an after-the-fact 100 point bounty.

Comment: are you worried that you will not get an answer that matches the requirements and are waiting to add a bounty? On that note, glad to see you on the site again. I do not think I have seen you in a while.

Comment: @Kortuk: I don't like SE's bounty system. I'd happily give away 100 points right now to some kind of escrow agent, but I don't want to have the points awarded by default. re: my absence -- life's short, things come up, I started here at a time of year when I had more free time....

Comment: I am still glad to see you return, and I can understand that. People probably used it as a method to flag a question and would just never award.

Comment: Agreed that the bounty system is flawed.  I never thought of working around it like that, though.  Good idea.

Comment: If you don't like the bounty system, there is always PayPal, etc. It seems that people put a bounty on questions in situations where it is of economic importance to them.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done on CCFL LCD monitors/TVs, so it seems pretty good. They use it for the inverter leads for the backlight. What you basically have is a 4 pin connector.

[image]

In this case the potential between conductors is about 1.44kV (for my particular 42" display.) So you could follow this example.

Now as you can see there is no return wire; that's because the shielding of the case is earthed. There must be sufficient isolation between the inverter lead and the case to avoid a short. The connector forms part of this shielding.

Also, note that on the PCB they only used a two pin connector. Probably because it was the smallest available, because isolation wouldn't be critical (there are holes in the PCB for this reason.)

Answer (score 0):

I know that Samtec can readily modify their connectors to omit pins (they do that to make differential pair variants of their QST/QSH line, for example) - that might be enough to give you the necessary creepage distance.

The bigger worry, though, is the flashing of the connector surface if the connector make/break under voltage.